# Cumulative distribution function of normal distribution as a series

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

According to Wikipedia the `cumulative distribution function` of the `standard normal distribution` can be approximated with the following series:

$\frac12 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} [x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{{3} * {5}} + ... + \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!} + ...]$

Can a series be used to approximate a normal distribution if $mu$ is not 0 and/or $\sigma$ is not 1?

Here is an `R` function that implements the above series for the standard normal.  However, I cannot figure out how to modify this series if $mu$ is not 0 and/or $\sigma$ is not 1:

```
my.cdf.function <- function(x) {
     n <- 201
     my.seq <- seq(1,n,by=2)
     my.cdf.series <- sum(sapply(1:length(my.seq), function(i) {x^my.seq[i] / cumprod(my.seq[1:i])[i]}))
     cdf.x = 1/2 + 1/((2 * pi)^0.5) * (exp(1)^((-x^2)/2)) * my.cdf.series
     return(cdf.x)
}

my.data <- data.frame(x = seq(-5,5,by=0.01))
my.output <- apply(my.data, 1, my.cdf.function)

pnorm.cdf <- pnorm(my.data$x, mean = 0, sd = 1)

all.equal(round(my.output,8), round(pnorm.cdf,8))
#[1] TRUE

plot(my.data$x, my.output)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is an alternative approach, also from Wikipedia, that works for the `standard normal`, but I have not been able to get it to work if $mu$ is not 0 and/or $\sigma$ is not 1:

$\Phi(x) = \frac12 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{2^k k! (2k+1)}$

Here is `R` code:

```
x1 <- -5.5
x2 <-  4
sigma <- 1
mu    <- 0
n <- 0:200
y1 <- 0.5+(1/((2*pi)^0.5))*sum((((-1)^n)*(x1^(2*n+1)))/((2^n)*(2*n+1)*factorial(n)))
y2 <- 0.5+(1/((2*pi)^0.5))*sum((((-1)^n)*(x2^(2*n+1)))/((2^n)*(2*n+1)*factorial(n)))
y2-y1
#[1] 0.9999683

pnorm(4, 0, 1)
#[1] 0.9999683
```

Comment: $P[X<x]=P[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}]=\Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$

Comment: I'm not sure if my comment makes sense. To find $P[X<x]$ for any normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, start by calculating $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, then evaluate the standard normal distribution function, $\Phi(y)$. You are done.

Comment: @JohnL Thank you.  I got a modified version of the first R function to work with your approach.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.  Otherwise I might go head and post the revised R function as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John L essentially answered my question in a comment.  He wrote: "To find $P[X<x]$ for any normally distributed random variable with mean $μ$ and standard deviation $σ$, start by calculating $y=\frac{x−μ}{σ}$, then evaluate the standard normal distribution function, $Φ(y)$. You are done."

I had been confused erroneously thinking I also needed to use $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Here is modified `R` code that implements John's approach.

```
# cdf of normal

mu <- 2
sigma <- 2

my.cdf.function <- function(x) {
     y <- (x - mu) / sigma
     n <- 201
     my.seq <- seq(1,n,by=2)
     my.cdf.series <- sum(sapply(1:length(my.seq), function(i) {y^my.seq[i] / cumprod(my.seq[1:i])[i]}))
     cdf.x = 1/2 + 1/((2 * pi)^0.5) * (exp(1)^((-y^2)/2)) * my.cdf.series
     return(cdf.x)
}

my.data <- data.frame(x = seq(-5.5,10,by=0.01))
my.output <- apply(my.data, 1, my.cdf.function)

pnorm.cdf <- pnorm(my.data$x, mean = 2, sd = 2)

all.equal(round(my.output,8), round(pnorm.cdf,8))
#[1] TRUE

jpeg(file="myplot3.jpeg")
plot(my.data$x, my.output)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Please _accept_ your own answer (perfectly OK to do so) bu clicking on the check mark in the left margin. This will stop the "Community"bot from throwing it into the queue of questions with no answers or answers with no votes whatsoever.